# RxJS Output an array of Subscription from multiple mergeMap

Tags: rxjs, observable

I was wondering if its possible to output an array ob observable after making multiple mergeMap calls

Here is an example f what i would like to get back

```
 this.kbSvc.create(kb).pipe(
            map(dbKb => kb = dbKb),
            mergeMap(() => this.goSvc.create(kb.id, "Build Market Share")),
            mergeMap(go => this.marketSvc.create(kb.id, (<GrowthOpportunity>go).id, "Market Segment - TBD")),
            mergeMap(ms => this.companySvc.create({ id: kb.id, msId: (<MarketSegment>ms).id }, "Company Type - TBD")),
        ).subscribe(([goSvc Result, marketSvc Result, companySvc Result]) => // //);
```

All of the calls above depend on each other there for i can not use `forkJoin`. In other words my previous observable must complete before invoking new one.

I am trying to avoid multiple `map` calls avfer each `mergeMap` and storing my resulted value from each observable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Operators I have come across so far doesn't maintain the state of the values received or emitted. Like the water stream, they just let the data flow after modifying the way they wish to.

One solution can be through nested pipe operators so you still have access to data from your previous operators.

Let's define all your observable under function for clarity.

```
goFunc(id) {
  return this.goSvc.create(id, "Build Market Share");
}

marketFunc(id, goData) {
  return this.marketSvc.create(id, (<GrowthOpportunity>goData).id, "Market Segment - TBD");
}

companyFunc(id, msData) {
  return this.companySvc.create({ id: id, msId: (<MarketSegment>msData).id }, "Company Type - TBD");
}
```

Here is the function for nested piping,

```
 someFunc() {

 this.kbSvc.create(kb).pipe(
  mergeMap(kb => this.goFunc(kb).pipe(
    mergeMap(goData => this.marketFunc(kb,goData).pipe(
      mergeMap(msData => this.companyFunc(kb,msData).pipe(
        map((companyData) => [goData,msData,companyData])
      )),
    ))
  ))
 ).subscribe(data => {
  //data will have [goData,msData,companyData]
  console.log(data);
 });

}
```

This should give the expected output.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was looking for in hopes of eliminating  nesting pipes. Thanks though.

Comment: If the solution worked for you, you can upvote. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options could be to use `combineLatest` like this -

```
this.kbSvc
        .create(kb)
        .pipe(
                map(dbKb => kb = dbKb),
                mergeMap(() => this.goSvc.create(kb.id, "Build Market Share")),
                mergeMap(go => {

                  return combinedLatest(of(go), this.marketSvc.create(kb.id, (<GrowthOpportunity>go).id, "Market Segment - TBD"));

                }),
                mergeMap(([goSvcResult, marketSvcResult]) => {
                  return combinedLatest(of([goSvcResult, marketSvcResult]), this.companySvc.create({ id: kb.id, msId: (<MarketSegment>marketSvcResult).id }, "Company Type - TBD"));
                })

        ).subscribe(([[goSvc Result, marketSvc Result], companySvc Result]) => // //);
```

Notice the subscribe callback input. Although it is not exactly what you expect still it is almost the same.

Comment: Thank you. 
I tried with combine latest still not really a neat subscription at the end.
I am just surprised that there is no operator that would allow something like this. I assume its pretty common scenario.